# Misplaced call `OnPreUpdate` in Auditor Event listener implementation in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I have a project by using NHibernate 3.
I used `Auditor Event Listener` in NHibernate for Trim of string properties in my entities.

My code is :

```
public class AuditorEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener, IPreUpdateEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent preInsertEvent)
    {
        Correction(preInsertEvent.Entity);
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent preUpdateEvent)
    {
        Correction(preUpdateEvent.Entity);
        return false;
    }

    internal static void Correction(object entity)
    {
        var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p =>  p.PropertyType == typeof(String));

        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            var result = item.GetValue(entity, null).ToString();
            result = result.Trim();
            item.SetValue(entity, result, null);
        }
    }
}
```

NHibernate config is :

```
<event type="pre-insert">
  <listener class="NS.NHibernate.AuditorEventListener, NS.NHibernate" />
</event>
<event type="pre-update">
  <listener class="NS.NHibernate.AuditorEventListener, NS.NHibernate" />
</event>
```

I used below commands for save and update for entities:

```
SessionInstance.Save(item);
SessionInstance.Update(item);
```

My problem is in save entity. 
When I call save method, `OnPreInsert`  method is called. 
When I call CommitTransaction() `OnPreUpdate` is called Automatically.

Also I used `Concurrency` in NHibernate and this Automatically `OnPreUpdate` call caused to value of `Version` property in database be `2` instead of `1` 
So far no problem 
but for next update of this entity concurrency error would happen because value of version in this entity is `1` but value of version in database is `2`.

Why is `OnPreUpdate` called?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but anyway whenever you update something in entity you also should update it in preInsertEvent.State/preUpdateEvent.State. For more information look at this post http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Why is OnPreUpdate called?

It looks like your "session.FlushMode" set in "FlushMode.Auto" or "FlushMode.Commit"
You can use "FlushMode.Never" but you have to explicitly call "session.Flush()"

Have you seen an opportunity to use interceptor, it looks more powerfully than EventListener

Comment: My `FlushMode` setting is in `Auto` mode and I need to this mode. I can not set it in `Never` mode because logic of my project not allowed me to do.